# If $\Sigma\ e_ka_k $ converges for every choice of $e_k\in \{-1,1\} $, prove that $\Sigma\ e_ka_k $ converges absolutely.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If $\Sigma\ e_ka_k $ converges for every choice of $e_k\in \{-1,1\} $, prove that $\Sigma\ e_ka_k $ converges absolutely.

Although I show the converse of this statement, I can't show above.

How can I prove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define
$$
f_k =
\begin{cases}
1 & a_k \geq 0 \\
-1 & a_k < 0
\end{cases}
$$
Then
$$
\sum_k |e_k a_k| = \sum_k |a_k| = \sum_k f_k a_k
$$
which converges by assumption.

Answer (score 2):

$\sum |a_k|=\sum a_ke_k$ where $e_k=1$ whence $a_k >0$ and $-1$ otherwise. Hence $\sum |a_k| <\infty$.